# Dúvida com API facebook

Tags: php, api, facebook

Tenho um blog e quero criar um botão de curtir/compartilhar os posts do blog no facebook. Colocar a opção para a pessoa curtir e compartilhar o post em cima dos comentários do blog. É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Sim é. Se não fosse a compartilha de videos do youtube no facebook não existia, ou existia somente através de link postado pelos utilizadores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim. É possível.

Existem os botões prontos no Facebook.

#### Compartilhar

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button?locale=pt_BR

#### Curtir

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Só seguir as instruções da página e ela monta os botões para você.

Comment: consegui implementar o botão de compartilhar, o botão de curtir quando clico nele, dá erro. Pq será?

Comment: Qual erro que apresenta ?